# How to customize the year view of the full calender

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I need some help. I need to customize the `year view` of the fullcalender from jquery plugin. I am explaining my code below.

```
function getCalendar() {
      var todayDate = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10);
      // var evStartDate = new Date(inputdate)
      //console.log('date',evStartDate);
      //addClassByDate(evStartDate);
      $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        theme: true,
        header: {
          left: 'prev,next',
          center: 'title',
          right: 'year,month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        ///////// edit
        dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {
          //alert('day click');
        },
        eventClick: function(event, jsEvent) {
          //alert('event clicked');
          $('#eventpopup').modal({
            backdrop: 'static'
          });
        },
        eventRender: function(event, element, view){
                    var evStart = moment(view.intervalStart).subtract(1, 'days');
                    var evEnd = moment(view.intervalEnd).subtract(1, 'days');
                    if (!event.start.isAfter(evStart) ||
                        event.start.isAfter(evEnd)) { return false; }
                },
        ///////////
        defaultDate: todayDate,
        navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
        editable: true,
        eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
        events: [{
          title: '1',
          start: '2017-12-01'
        }, {
          title: '2',
          start: '2017-12-02'
        }, {
          id: 999,
          title: '5',
          start: '2017-11-02'
        }]
      });
    }
```

Here In my month view all numbers(`i.e-1,2...`) is shown in date wise but in case of `year view` it showing multiple. Here I need some changes in case of year view means the total count like `2+1` will be shown in month wise. Let say for this example in month of December the total count should be `3` similarly in month of November the total count should  `5` when only user click on year view. [Here is my plunkr example](https://plnkr.co/edit/IteH1fikjToq4VYVRFVQ?p=preview). Instead of showing the multiple number i need to display the total number as per one month in case of `year view`.

Comment: There's no "year" view by default in fullCalendar (see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/views/Available_Views/). Have you made a customised view? Also none of the code you've shown above appears to be related to counting the events in each month, which I think is your problem? I don't think you've given us the necessary information to actually help you, unfortunately.

Comment: @ADyson : No,Its already there inside `fullcalendar.js` file. You can visit that plunkr link and check.

Comment: @ADyson : Actually I have these events for month view and I need to convert it while click on year view.

Comment: Please use the Edit feature to place into the question itself the code which you're using to try and do this. No-one is going to search through whole of your plunker to find the relevant bit. None of what you've shown above appears to be related to what you're describing.

Comment: As for the year view, I can see it's in the source, but according to https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/1140 it's not officially released yet, so you cannot guarantee it does not have any bugs in it which could affect what you're trying to do. Use it by all means, but just understand it may not be perfect.